# How can I make a condition for currently viewed language on a template file?

Tags: 6, i18n-l10n, theming

I have a template called `page-my-view.tpl.php` that overrides a view page `my-view`.

I have directly put the title tags, description and h1 on this template file.

However I need different texts for these tags per language to avoid duplicated tags.

I have 2 languages on my site English and Japanese. 
Japanese is the default one with no prefix and English is with prefix "en".

So how can I make a condition on this template for currently viewed language?

Comment: You could use the `$language` variable. `$language->language` holds the language code. To put logical code in your template is not the best way though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template file global variable `$language` is avaible,with below properties

**'language' => 'en',

'name' => 'English',

'native' => 'English',

'direction' => 0,

'enabled' => 1,

'plurals' => 0,

'formula' => '',

'domain' => '',

'prefix' => '',

'weight' => 0,

'javascript' => ''**

You can achieve your jobs with something like this 
// if global variable $language  not avaible uncomment first line

```
 //    global $language;
if ($language->language == 'en') {
   // do your desires
  }
```

Comment: Note that page templates already have the `$language` variable. No need for `global $language;`.

Comment: I know it my friend,I say it because he/she understand $language is global  :).

Comment: I guess that's a good reason, but as it stands now, he/she might as well think that it's not and start to always use `global $language`. :)

Comment: appreciate .You right. :).

Comment: Your welcome :)